# Apollo Client 400 Error - bundle.esm.js:60 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to connect to the apollo-client in my react application and I am getting error 400 when i run the query. If i use the same url with the same query in the postman, it works perfectly. Thank you guys

I have already tried using the apollo-link but could not get it working.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({

    uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
    onError: (e) => { console.log(e) },
})

client.query({

    query: gql`
    {
        contracts{
            id
        }
    } `
}).then(data => console.log(`Query Result ${data}`))
```

**Error in the Browser!!**

```
{operation: {…}, networkError: ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 400
    at throwServerError (http://loca…, graphQLErrors: undefined, forward: ƒ}forward: ƒ (op)graphQLErrors: undefinednetworkError: ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 400
    at throwServerError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37934:17)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37959:13operation: {variables: {…}, extensions: {…}, operationName: null, query: {…}, setContext: ƒ, …}__proto__: Object
bundle.esm.js:60 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400
    at new ApolloError (bundle.esm.js:60)
    at QueryManager.<anonymous> (bundle.esm.js:1184)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:97)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:78)
    at tslib.es6.js:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (tslib.es6.js:67)
    at bundle.esm.js:1147
    at bundle.esm.js:1627
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at bundle.esm.js:1626
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at QueryManager../node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.esm.js.QueryManager.broadcastQueries (bundle.esm.js:1621)
    at bundle.esm.js:1127
```

I am just trying to console log the result of the query to test

Comment: As @Jhm has said in the comment on an answer below. Check your response for the request in the network tab. It should have some more information.

Answer (score 0):

Add a forward slash to end of the uri so it's like http://localhost:3000/graphql/
Might been irrelevant but it makes a difference.

Comment: Does not make any difference. The same url and query works with fetch and postman. Any thoughts

Comment: Have checked out what the failed request response says from the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the fetch policy. If you are using current react hooks then use something like this

```
import { useQuery, useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

const Login = () => {
    const [signInResponse] = useMutation(SIGNIN_USER);

    const onSubmit = async (e) => {
        const response = await signInResponse({
            variables:{email:'email',password:'password'},
            errorPolicy:"all"
        });
        console.log(response)
        // dispatch({type:"LOGIN",payload:response.data})
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the following to your Apollo client:

const client = new ApolloClient({
uri,
cache: new InMemoryCache(),
defaultOptions: {
watchQuery: {
fetchPolicy: 'cache-first'
},
query: {
fetchPolicy: 'cache-first'
},
}
});